# how to configure radio registers of cc2500 and cc2511 to 250 Kbps and 500 Kbps?

Tags: microcontroller, communication, rfid

-I'm using  **cc2500** and **cc2511** transceivers in my project.One in transmitting data, and the other is receiving

-I am using cc2500 at target board and cc2511 at host side.

-I am able to communicate this two device at 2.5 Kbps.

-My question is, how can I get the 500kbps and 250Kbps  transmission rate??

-I tried register value generate from  smart RF studio for both cc2500 and cc2511 but some how i am not able to trans receive .my Xtal frequency for cc2500 is 2410MHz and for cc2511 is 48MHz.

-I tried various setting like change in  filter bandwidth ,deviation ,modulation format but badly i am not able to communicate this two chip at 250 and 500 Kbps.

-Please give me register setting or help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

your CC2500's Xtal frequency cannot be 2410MHz.. It should be 26 to 27MHz, per your crystal.
Check the actual frequency of both source and target, make sure the difference between them is within specifications (80ppm max).
TI's EE community is a better place for such questions.

Comment: Yes You are write.My cc2500 chip's Xtal frequency is 27 MHz not a 2410 MHz.